# Why does 0.13.6 download Scala 2.10.4 by default?

Tags: sbt

Why SBT 0.13.6 is downloading Scala 2.10.4 by default?
Even if in `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtopts` it is written `Scala version (default: latest release)` which seems to not be true.

```
C:\Users\Joan>sbt scala-version
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi
        confs: [default]
        1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (111kB/15ms)
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.6 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        44 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (13750kB/563ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.4 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24459kB/375ms)
[info] Set current project to joan (in build file:/C:/Users/Joan/)
[info] 2.10.4
```

Cheers

Comment: sbt itself still uses Scala 2.10.4. That says nothing about the projects you compile with it, though, so if you ask for 2.11.2 for your project, it'll retrieve that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `sbt` is built on scala 2.10.4, as you can easily verify [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/project/Sbt.scala#L22).

In your own project, simply specify the scala version you indend to use in the same way sbt does, i.e. providing the `scalaVersion` build setting.

It's generally speaking a good idea not to depend on a default.

Comment: Humm, so I guess I need to specify every time in each project the version 2.11 if I want it?

Comment: Yes, in the same way sbt does in it's own project, you need to specify the `scalaVersion` build setting. It's generally speaking a good idea, since you don't want to depend on a default that may change in the future.